# showing wrong current time

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2, nsdateformatter

My clock time is 2012-04-12 09:37:01 +0000 however the output from my code is showing a 2h delay. Does somebody now why?

```
NSDate *today;
today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

--- In output field / debugger ==>

```
(lldb) po today
(NSDate *) $3 = 0x06a3a8c0 2012-04-12 07:37:01 +0000
```

Answer (score 5):

`2012-04-12 07:37:01 +0000` is a GMT time representation (Greenwich Time). Maybe you are in the +0200 (Eastern European) time zone? If so, the time representation is correct. If not, you should configure your device or system to the correct time zone of your location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the error was that the date was generated from the ipad timezone (that in my case was different that the Mac timezone). Can you check it?